# UNIX script to convert queries

Tags: oracle, shell, scripting

I need a UNIX shell script to convert my queries from Java compatible to Oracle compatible format. ie.

I have all the java compatible queries:

java:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f,g "+//    "from test where year(timestamp)=year(today) and month(timestamp)=month(today) " 
+//    "and day(timestamp)=2 and h='" + "W" + "'"
```

Oracle

> SELECT a, b, c,d,e,f,g from test where
>   year(timestamp)=year(today) and
>   month(timestamp)=month(today)  and
>   day(timestamp)=2 and h='W'

Is it possible using sed or awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all, keep all your text in a single line.**

You can do it with one-line Perl code:

```
perl -n -E 's/"[^"]+"//mg;s/"$//;print' java-sql.txt >oracle-sql.txt
```

It will remove the tail `"' also.
If you don't have a file, the pipe is also working here

```
you-code-print-java-sql-to-stdout.exe | perl -n -E 's/"[^"]+"//g;s/"$//;print'
```

You will get the oracle version from the stdout of Perl.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/SELECT/s/"[^"]\+"//g' <FILE>
```

Might help, but only if the query has balanced "s on the same line. E.g. it fails for:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f,g "+//    
"from test where day(timestamp)=2 and h='" + "W" + "'
```

HTH